# SQL DELETE From with sub query syntax error

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am having difficulty runing SQL code in MS Access 2010. I would like to ask for help in reviewing and correcting it.

**Data:** 
- two tables with names: `Tbl_001_WholeBase` and `Tbl_002_NewKVG` 
- they have connected by column named `Key`

**Problem:** 
I want to delete all rows from `Tbl_001_WholeBase` which have `Key` that is not available in table `Tbl_002_NewKVG`

**Example:** 
 
    **Tbl_001_WholeBase**

```
ID Key
1  Hronic1
2  Hronic2
3  Hronic3
```

**Tbl_002_NewKVG**

```
ID Key 
1  Hronic1 
2  Hronic2
```

So as a result I would like to leave in `Tbl_001_WholeBase` only 3rd record, base would look like this:

```
ID Key
3  Hronic3
```

**What I wanted to use in Access was:**

```
DELETE 
FROM Tbl_001_WholeBase 
WHERE Tbl_001_WholeBase.KEY IN 
(SELECT * 
FROM Tbl_001_WholeBase 
LEFT JOIN Tbl_002_NewKVG 
ON Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key = Tbl_002_NewKVG.Key 
WHERE (((Tbl_002_NewKVG.Key) Is Null)));
```

The subquery is working properly, however I can't connect it with Delete statement.


**Error I got when running this code is:**

> You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the Exists reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field.

Comment: Select specific column in Subquery instead of *

Comment: Replace the  * symbol by a field match with the  Tbl_001_WholeBase.KEY
in the subquery after IN operator.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do not ever use select * , unless that is what you need. That thing, from my experience, is the single most common database performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a key in subquery instead of (*)

```
DELETE 
FROM Tbl_001_WholeBase 
WHERE Tbl_001_WholeBase.KEY IN 
(SELECT keyId 
FROM Tbl_001_WholeBase 
LEFT JOIN Tbl_002_NewKVG 
ON Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key = Tbl_002_NewKVG.Key 
WHERE (((Tbl_002_NewKVG.Key) Is Null)));
```

Here `keyId` will be your column name or your unique key through which you want to delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables using a `LEFT JOIN`.

This will return all records from the table on the left of the join, and any matching records from the table on the right.  `NULL` is used where the record on the right isn't available.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Tbl_001_WholeBase LEFT JOIN Tbl_001_NewKVG ON Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key = Tbl_001_NewKVG.Key  

| Tbl_001_WholeBase.ID | Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key | Tbl_001_NewKVG.ID | Tbl_001_NewKVG.Key |
|----------------------|-----------------------|-------------------|--------------------|
| 1                    | Hronic1               | 1                 | Hronic1            |
| 2                    | Hronic2               | 2                 | Hronic2            |
| 3                    | Hronic3               | NULL              | NULL               |
```

You can see that the last `NewKVG.Key` is NULL, so you can omit it from the results:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Tbl_001_WholeBase LEFT JOIN Tbl_001_NewKVG ON Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key = Tbl_001_NewKVG.Key
WHERE   NOT Tbl_001_NewKVG.Key IS NULL  

| Tbl_001_WholeBase.ID | Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key | Tbl_001_NewKVG.ID | Tbl_001_NewKVG.Key |
|----------------------|-----------------------|-------------------|--------------------|
| 1                    | Hronic1               | 1                 | Hronic1            |
| 2                    | Hronic2               | 2                 | Hronic2            |
```

Or you can delete it from the table:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW Tbl_001_WholeBase.*
FROM    Tbl_001_WholeBase LEFT JOIN Tbl_001_NewKVG ON Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key = Tbl_001_NewKVG.Key
WHERE   NOT Tbl_001_NewKVG.Key IS NULL  

| ID       | Key      |
|----------|----------|
| #Deleted | #Deleted |
| #Deleted | #Deleted |
| 3        | Hronic3  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM Tbl_001_WholeBase 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Tbl_002_NewKVG
              WHERE Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key = Tbl_002_NewKVG.Key 
             );
```

Or use `IN` with no `JOIN`:

```
DELETE FROM Tbl_001_WholeBase 
WHERE Tbl_001_WholeBase.Key IN (SELECT Tbl_002_NewKVG.Key
                                FROM Tbl_002_NewKVG
                               );
```